# Angular selector returns me word object instead of value [object]

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this selector that pulls data from a services.

When I select any of the options that appear, it appears in the console:

{enterprises: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]', warehouses: ''}
enterprises
:
"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
warehouses
:
""

Enterprises are the companies that I can select and warehouses are the warehouses that I can select.

[image: My selected]

Does anyone know why?

My html:

```
            <select class="form-select" formControlName="enterprises" (change)="updateSelectValues()">
              <option value="" disabled selected="selected">SELECCIONA LA EMPRESA</option>
              <option [value]="enterprises" *ngFor="let item of enterprises">{{item.name}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div style="margin-top: 10px">
            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" formControlName="warehouses"
              (change)="updateSelectValues()">
              <option value="" disabled selected="selected">SELECCIONA EL TALLER</option>
              <option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of warehouses">{{item.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

My ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { DatosService, EmpresaTaller } from '../services/datos.service';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  token = "";
  userName = "";
  error = "";

  enterprise=-1;
  warehouse=-1;

  enterprises = [];
  warehouses = [];

  seleccionado;

  selectForm: FormGroup;

  cargaCount = 0;
  cargaTrasiego = 0;
  descargaCount = 0;
  descargaTrasiego = 0;

  constructor(
    private datosService: DatosService, 
    private fb: FormBuilder, 
    private api:ApiService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.token=sessionStorage.getItem('authToken');
    this.userName=sessionStorage.getItem('userName');

    this.api.getEnterprises(this.token, this.userName).subscribe(responseEnterprises=>{
      const {result, value} = responseEnterprises;
      if(result !== 0 || !value || !value.Rows || value.Rows.length === 0){
        this.error='Error, usuario sin empresas';
        return;
      }
      this.enterprises=value.Rows.map(enterprise=>{
        const {CODIGO: code, EMPRESA: name} = enterprise;
        return {code, name};
      });
      this.enterprise = this.enterprises[0].code;


      this.api.getWarehouses(this.token, this.userName, this.enterprise).subscribe(responseWarehouses=>{
        const {result, value} = responseWarehouses;
        if(result !== 0 || !value || !value.Rows || value.Rows.length === 0){
          this.error='Error, usuario sin almacenes';
          return;
        }
        this.warehouses=value.Rows.map(warehouse=>{
          const {CODIGO: code, ALMACEN: name} = warehouse;
          return {code, name};
        });
        this.warehouse = this.warehouses[0].code;

        this.api.getDashboard(this.token, this.userName, this.enterprise, this.warehouse).subscribe(responseDashboard=>{
          const {result, value} = responseDashboard;
          if(result !== 0 || !value || !value.Rows || value.Rows.length === 0){
            this.error='Error, no ha devuelto dashboard';
            return;
          }
          this.cargaCount = value.Rows[0].orden_carga_count;
          this.cargaTrasiego = value.Rows[0].orden_carga_trasiego_count;
          this.descargaCount = value.Rows[0].orden_descarga_count;
          this.descargaTrasiego = value.Rows[0].orden_descarga_trasiego_count;
        });

      });

    });

    this.selectForm = this.fb.group({
      enterprises: [''],
      warehouses: ['']
    });
  }

  updateSelectValues() {
    this.datosService.updateEmpresaTaller(this.selectForm.value as EmpresaTaller);
  }

}
```

Then, once selected, I want what is selected to appear at the top of another page, but this appears:

[image: My image]

My html:

```
<header class="sticky-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="overflow: hidden">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="badge bg-primary text-wrap">
            <p>{{(datosEmpresaTaller | async).enterprises}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px">
          <div class="badge bg-primary text-wrap">
            <p>{{(datosEmpresaTaller | async).warehouses}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <form class="d-flex">
        <button class="btn btn-outline" type="submit" routerLink='/dashboard'> <img src="assets/icons/menu.png"
            alt="Cerrar Sesión" height="100" width="120" /></button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

My ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DatosService, EmpresaTaller } from '../services/datos.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  datosEmpresaTaller: Observable<EmpresaTaller>;

  constructor(private datosService: DatosService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datosEmpresaTaller = this.datosService.getEmpresaTaller();
  }
  
}
```

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export interface EmpresaTaller {
  enterprises: string,
  warehouses: string
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatosService {
  private selectValues = new BehaviorSubject<EmpresaTaller>({enterprises: '', warehouses: ''});

  constructor() { }

  updateEmpresaTaller(values: EmpresaTaller) {
    this.selectValues.next(values);
    console.log(values)
  }

  getEmpresaTaller() {
    return this.selectValues.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have set all `enterprises` as `mat-option` value.

Change this:

```
<option [value]="enterprises" *ngFor="let item of enterprises">{{item.name}}</option>
```

to:

```
<option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of enterprises">{{item.name}}</option>
```

Comment: @herreronegro In warehouses it does say item and the same thing keeps happening